# Toggle dropdown for each @item

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I need the code below to toggle on @item["name"]. But dropdown displays for all items (5 entries) instead of one at a time.

How can I change this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".name").click(function () {
            $(".dropdown").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Table:

```
<table class="diag" style="background: url('.png');border:none">
     <tbody>
          @foreach (var item in Model.project)
          {                            
               @:<tr>
                 <td class="image">
                     <img src="@item["image"]" />
                 </td>
                 <td class="name">@item["name"]</td>

                 <td class="dropdown">
                    <ul>
                       <li>Option 1</li>
                       <li>Option 2</li>
                       <li>Option 3</li>
                       <li>Option 4</li>
                       <li>Option 5</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>

              @:</tr>
           }
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is toggling all 5 because all 5 option lists have the same class name "dropdown", so you click on any name as it is and they all will toggle

A quick fix is to use the context of the click so you know which option list to show/hide

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").hide();
    $(".name").click(function () {
         $(this).next(".dropdown").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle showing it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/LgSbX/)

**EDIT:** added initial hide based on comment below

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to have dropdowns open when page runs for first time, how can I do this.

Comment: simple, just add $(".dropdown").hide(); before the $(".name").click part